# Use elevated background color for iOS 13 dark mode modal UINavigationBar?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicolor, ios13, ios-darkmode

I'm adapting my app to iOS 13 dark mode, and it looks like modal views in iOS 13 have a card-like design like the following:

[image]

Notably, while the navbar is white in light mode, it is not black in dark mode but instead is using some elevated system color. I think this looks pretty nice.

My question is how do I do the same in my app? I'm simply doing the following now:

```swift
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
```

which while adapting to dark mode shows up completely black (no elevation):

[image]

How can I make it the same as in Apple apps?

Comment: Do you _have to_ style the navigation bar in any way? I figured it's best do just leave the system defaults for everything (in iOS 13).

Comment: @FrankSchlegel thanks for the reply! Yeah I guess worst case I can just leave it as default - I just feel when I'm using a system color it should somehow honor the elevation..

Comment: Yes it should. But there's a lot more going on with navigation bars. I think you have to set the `backgroundImage` to an empty `UIImage()` and set `opaque = true` in order to have it actually use the `backgroundColor` correctly...

Comment: Also try setting `isTranslucent = false` and setting the `barTintColor`.

Comment: try UIColor.tertiarySystemFill